# Julia equivalent of pad_width in np.pad

Tags: julia, padding, zero-padding

Numpy has a [padding function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) with a `pad_width` parameter that  does the following:

`pad_width`: Number of values padded to the edges of each axis. `((before_1, after_1), ... (before_N, after_N))` unique pad widths for each axis. `(before, after)` or `((before, after),)` yields same before and after pad for each axis. `(pad,)` or `int` is a shortcut for before = after = pad width for all axes.

Is there an equivalent function in Julia with similar functionality for zero-padding? Creating a 2D matrix with complex data and zero-padding in Python:

```
# Python Implementation
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((620, 327)) + np.random.random((620, 327)) * 1j
padWidths = ((12,12),(327,327))
# Returns an array of size (644, 981) as the pad_widths parameter specified 
# zero-padding of length 644 = 620 + 12 + 12 and 981 =  327 + 327 + 327
zeroPaddedData = np.pad(data, padWidths)
```

Performing a similar analysis with a 2D complex array in Julia:

```
# Julia Implementation
using Random
using PaddedViews
using ImageFiltering

data = randn(ComplexF32, (620, 327))
padWidth = ((12,12),(327,327))

# This returns an array of size (620,327)
zeroPaddedDataOne= PaddedView(0, data,(620,327))

# This returns an array of size (620,981)
zeroPaddedDataTwo = padarray(data, Fill(0,(0,327)))

# This returns an array of size (644,327)
zeroPaddedDataThree= padarray(data, Fill(0,(12,0)))

# This returns an array of size (644,981)
zeroPaddedDataFour = padarray(data, Fill(0,(12,327)))

# This doesn't work as you can't pass in a tuple of tuples into an array with 2-dimensions
zeroPaddedDataFive = padarray(data, Fill(0,padWidth))
zeroPaddedDataSix = PaddedView(0, data,padWidth)
```

It appears that one solution is to use

```
zeroPaddedData = padarray(data, Fill(0,(12,327)))
```

to match the functionality of `pad_width` in Numpy (which, instead of passing in a tuple of tuples, is a single tuple containing the amount of padding to perform along each dimension of the array). Is this the recommended approach to match the `pad_width` parameter in Numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PaddedViews the first tuple parameter provides the size and the second a location of the top left corner the original matrix in the padded matrix.
For an example consider a matrix:

```
julia> data = rand(0:9,2,3)+im*rand(0:9,2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Complex{Int64}}:
 8+8im  7+2im  9+0im
 8+0im  2+5im  3+9im
```

Than after padding you would get:

```
julia> collect(PaddedView(Complex{Int32}(0),data,(4,6),(2,2)))
4×6 Matrix{Complex{Int64}}:
 0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im
 0+0im  8+8im  7+2im  9+0im  0+0im  0+0im
 0+0im  8+0im  2+5im  3+9im  0+0im  0+0im
 0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im  0+0im
```

The new matrix is 4x6 (first tuple parameter (4,6)) and the original matrix starts at the location (2,2).

So what you are looking for is probably:

```
zeroPaddedData= PaddedView(ComplexF32(0.), data, (620 + 12 + 12, 327 + 327 + 327),(12+1, 327+1))
```

This will yield the size 644x981 and place `data` inside it starting at the location (13,328) having the pads like your Python code. You might want to materialize your padded matrix by using `collect` as in my example.